# Firebase can't set RemoteConfig defaults

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm using the `RemoteConfig` framework of Firebase.
Fetching data from the Firebase server works fine (already working in production), but setting defaults doesn't seem to work. I tried to stick to the documentation, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

To test this I did the following:

```
[self.remoteConfig setDefaults:@{@"key1": @"value1"}];
```

Then, in the `Firebase Console` I set parameter `key1` to have the default `No Value` that sends zero data to the client. I didn't define any other conditions, so this is the only value that will be sent. According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters), the `RemoteConfig` object should pick the defaults in this case.

Fetching code:

```
[self.remoteConfig fetchWithExpirationDuration:self.configurationExpirationDuration
                           completionHandler:^(FIRRemoteConfigFetchStatus status,
                                               NSError * _Nullable error) {
  if (status == FIRRemoteConfigFetchStatusSuccess) {
    [self.remoteConfig activateFetched];

    FIRRemoteConfigValue *remoteValue1 = [self.remoteConfig configValueForKey:@"key1"];
    NSString *value1 = remoteValue1.stringValue;

    // Logic comes here

  } else {
    LogError(@"Error fetching remote configuration from Firebase: %@", error);
}
```

`remoteValue1` is not `nil`.

`value1` is `nil`.

`remoteValue1.dataValue` is `_NSZeroData`.

Moreover, when I try to use

```
[self.remoteConfig defaultValueForKey:@"key1" namespace:nil]
```

I get a `nil` value (assuming that sending `nil` to as the `namespace` parameter will give me the default namespace defaults).

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`configValueForKey:` method firstly checks fetching results from Firebase server, if the results exist, it returns the remote results instead of defaults.

So key1 value should be what you set in console, which is `nil` (no value).

When you call `defaultVaueForKey:namespace:` you should always use default namespace `FIRNamespaceGoogleMobilePlatform`. Using `nil` will not return any valid config results.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed the `FIRNamespaceGoogleMobilePlatform` const in the header file.

Comment: For Swift developers - the namespace is `NamespaceGoogleMobilePlatform`, declared in `FIRRemoteConfig.h`